# Why does the conditional expectation minimize L2 loss?

Tags: regression, conditional-expectation

The claim is that, for a regression task, the conditional regression function $f(x) = \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{Y}|\mathbf{X}=x]$ minimizes the L2 loss $\arg\min(\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{Y} - f(\mathbf{X})]^2)$. I can see why it's true for a normal distribution. But why is it true in general?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find $\arg\min(\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{Y} - f(\mathbf{X}|\theta)]^2)$ you get the first order condition
$$\frac \partial {\partial \theta} \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{Y} - f(\mathbf{X}|\theta)]^2=0$$
The differentiation is with respect to the parameters $\theta$ of your model $f(x|\theta)$. Proceed with differentiationg:
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[\frac \partial {\partial \theta}(\mathbf{Y} - f(\mathbf{X}|\theta))^2\right]=
\mathbb{E}\left[-2(\mathbf{Y} - f(\mathbf{X}|\theta))\frac \partial {\partial \theta}f(\mathbf{X}|\theta)\right]=
$$
$$\mathbb{E}\left[(\mathbf{Y} - f(\mathbf{X}|\theta))\right](-2\frac \partial {\partial \theta}f(\mathbf{X}|\theta) )
$$
This holds when the following condition holds:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[(\mathbf{Y} - f(\mathbf{X}|\theta))\right]=0$$
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{Y}\right]=  f(\mathbf{X}|\theta)$$

Comment: Why were you able to pull out $-2\frac \partial {\partial \theta}f(\mathbf{X}|\theta)$?

Comment: @Ryker, if you have your function constant for any input data X then it's a trivial solution with all coefficients zero, no?

Comment: Which function is constant, the derivative?